# Split space separated elements into separate lines

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, grep

If I have a file with non-predictable elements separated with spaces like:

```
ABC123
ABC124
ABC125  ABC321  ABC222  ABC111  ABC333
ABC069  ABC450  ABC595
```

How can I print each of them in a separate line? (python or grep/awk, etc.)

Comment: Could you please show your attempts?

Comment: awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file worked for me. I had tried tr -s ' ' '\n' < file without success before.

Comment: @user1658415: That suggests that you didn't just have _spaces_ between your words, but also _tabs_; in that case, `tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < file` should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

If you have only spaces:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < file
```

If you have spaces and tabs, then as suggested by @mklement0:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < file
```

OR

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file
```

OR

```
egrep -o 'ABC[[:digit:]]{3}' file
```

OR

```
egrep -o '[[:alnum:]]{6}' file
```

Comment: Thank you! The `awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file` worked for me. I had tried `tr -s ' ' '\n' < file` without success before. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

***sed*** command approach:

```
sed -E 's/\s+/\n/g' testfile
```

`-E` option, allows extended regular expressions

---

***awk*** approach:

```
awk '{gsub(/ +/, "\n", $0); print}' testfile
```

> ***gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])***
>         Search *target* for *all* of the longest, leftmost, *nonoverlapping* matching substrings it can find and
>         replace them with *replacement*. The ‘*g*’ in gsub() stands for “global,”
>   which means replace       everywhere.

---

***grep*** approach:

```
grep -o '\S*' testfile
```

`\S*` - matches all non-whitespace sequences

Comment: Good solutions; worth noting that your `sed` and `grep` commands only work with the _GNU_ implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Note: All the solutions below process the input file *line by line*, to avoid having to load the entire file into memory, and work with line-internal tabs as well as spaces.

Using standard Unix utilities, the **POSIX-compliant `tr` solution** from [VIPIN KUMAR's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42702892/45375) is both **efficient and simple**, his POSIX-compliant `awk` solution works well too; a simpler non-POSIX-compliant solution is possible - see below.

The ***generalized* version of the `tr`** command that also handles line-internal *tab* characters:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < file
```

Using ***GNU* `awk` or Mawk** (but not BSD/macOS `awk`):

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '1' file
```

Using **grep** (works with both GNU and BSD/macOS `grep`):

```
grep -Eo '\S+' file
```

Using **Python** (both v2 and v3):

Shell one-liner (`bash`, due to use of `$'...'`):

```
python -c $'import fileinput\nfor line in fileinput.input(): print("\\n".join(line.split()))' file
```

In a script:

```
for line in open('file'):
  print("\n".join(line.split()))
```

Using **Ruby**:

Shell one-liner:

```
ruby -ne 'puts $_.split' file
```

In a script:

```
File.open('file').each_line do |line|
  puts line.split
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split:

```
a = '''ABC123
ABC124
ABC125  ABC321  ABC222  ABC111  ABC333
ABC069  ABC450  ABC595'''

for item in a.split():
    print(item)
```

gives:

```
ABC123
ABC124
ABC125
ABC321
ABC222
ABC111
ABC333
ABC069
ABC450
ABC595
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs`:

```
xargs -n 1 < file
```

Output:

```
ABC123
ABC124
ABC125
ABC321
ABC222
ABC111
ABC333
ABC069
ABC450
ABC595
```

Comment: While this is alluringly short, it creates a `/bin/echo` child process for each input argument, which is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("testfile.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    newLine = line
    newLine = newLine.replace("\n","")
    newLine = newLine.split(" ")
    for eachElement in newLine:
        if eachElement!="" and len(eachElement)!=0:
            print eachElement
```